# Database Connectivity in IBM Bluemix API

Tags: database-connection, ibm-cloud

I am working in IBM Bluemix Open API and I want to connect my database to IBM Bluemix. I cannot connect. Please help me. Are there any services for database connectivity?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? Please be more specific about the difficulties that you are encountering. I have suggested that the bluemix tag be added and I am waiting for my peer review to be completed.

Comment: Is your database behind firewall (or) Internet accessible ? As Bill said, please provide more details (Example : Code snippet , Log error message , Database type etc. )